# Dropdown menus not working as expected in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigation, bootstrap-4

The dropdown menus in my website just refuse to work and I cannot see why. I've looked through this site and others, as well as rereading the bootstrap documentation but I just have no idea why it is not working. They will not dropdown. I know that they are being clicked because the hash symbol will appear in the URL when I do click them, but no drop animation occurs.

Below is my code, with the head and navbar.

Can anyone else see what is wrong?

```
<head>
    <title>Scott's Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles/bootstrap/css/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
        <div class="container bg-dark">
            <div class="pl-3 pr-3 pt-3 pb-0 row bg-dark text-light">
                <div class="col-9">
                    <h1>Scott McMullan</h1>
                    <div class="row pt-0 pb-0 pl-0 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <h7 class="font-weight-light">Studying full time at Griffith University.</h7>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pt-0 pb-3 pl-0 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
                        <div class="col">
                            <h7 class="font-weight-light">Working towards a bachelor of Computer Science, majoring in Data Science & Artificial Intelligence.</h7>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr/>

                    <div class="row pt-0 pb-3 pl-0 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                <img src="icon.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="mannaz" />
                            </a>
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="index.html">Home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                            aria-expanded="false">
                                            Experience
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Professional</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Academic</a>
                                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Academic Course Breakdown</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                            aria-expanded="false">
                                            Projects
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Professional</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Academic</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Personal</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your dropdown wasn't working is because you weren't loading the **popper.js**. That file is needed for all things that pop up and drop down.

Also, it's always a good idea to keep your HTML as valid as you can manage (the code you posted here wasn't valid). And loading the js files at the bottom is recommended (instead of loading them in the head).

Here's the working code (click the "run code snippet" button and expand to full screen to verify it's working):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
    <div class="container bg-dark">
        <div class="pl-3 pr-3 pt-3 pb-0 row bg-dark text-light">
            <div class="col-9">
                <h1>Scott McMullan</h1>
                <div class="row pt-0 pb-0 pl-0 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
                    <div class="col-9">
                        <h7 class="font-weight-light">Studying full time at Griffith University.</h7>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row pt-0 pb-3 pl-0 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h7 class="font-weight-light">Working towards a bachelor of Computer Science, majoring in Data Science &amp; Artificial Intelligence.</h7>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr/>

                <div class="row pt-0 pb-3 pl-0 pr-3 bg-dark text-light">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/60" width="30" height="30" alt="mannaz" />
                        </a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="index.html">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                       aria-expanded="false">
                                        Experience
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Professional</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Academic</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Academic Course Breakdown</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                       aria-expanded="false">
                                        Projects
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Professional</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Academic</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Personal</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What others are saying is not true, I was loading the popper.js from a local file. What was not being loaded, however, was the jquery file because I had everything locally.

The fix was simple, download the jquery source from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js and link it with my HTML locally.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you'll have to read the bootstrap-documentation again:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

The Bootstrap dropdown you're using requires popper.js
To be found right at the introduction at
Quick Start > JS

The Bootstrap documentation is quite resourceful. Usually it's all right there ;)

Comment: I see, thanks. Why is that not in the files I downloaded? I have bootstrap on my PC locally.

Comment: Since I didn't package it, I do not know for sure, but I'd say those are optional, third party dependencies not managed by the bootstrap-team.You'll find the sources for download with a quick web-search though.

Answer (score -1):

Well, learned something new myself:
PopperJS actually comes bundled with bootstrap-4. It's just hidden within the bootstrap.bundle.js

You'll have to include that though.
And as I‘ve said in my last answer:
It's all in the docs!

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Sorry for being so bum, but you said you had read the documentation yourself. And since it's there, I see no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I included 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="styles/bootstrap/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>` 
in my source, but that still does not help.